# Error loading Gridview into Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to load a gridview into a pre-existing one so the layout would be similar to this:

```
 Branch Account Name Type Sub Hold LOC
 central 1234   John  sc  s   5000 20

 Financial Gridview for above account would appear here

 Branch Account Name Type Sub Hold LOC
 central 1234   Jane  sc  s   1000 20

 Financial Gridview for above account would appear here

 And so on....
```

In the financial gridview i'd display all of the account holder's financials. I was hoping to accomplish this by loading in another gridview with the information but I keep encountering the following error when it tries to add it in: Cannot set column 'branch'. The value violates the MaxLength limit of this column.

my LoadData method is below:

```
Private Sub LoadData()

    conn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    ds = New DataSet("Accounts")
    da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [branch], [no] , [surname], [name], [type], [sub], [totalAmount], loc, HoldCalc, odTimes " & _
                            "FROM [DmdOD]", conn)

    Dim branchQuery As String = "central"

    Dim gridFinance As New GridView

    If ListBranch.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing Then
        branchQuery = ListBranch.SelectedItem.ToString()
    End If

    conn.Open()

    da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "Accounts")
    da.Fill(ds, "Accounts")

    Dim tblAccounts As DataTable
    tblAccounts = ds.Tables("Accounts")

    Dim dsFinance = New DataSet("Finance")
    Dim dsFinanceTemp = New DataSet("FinanceTemp")
    Dim daFinance = New SqlDataAdapter()

    Dim tblFinance As DataTable
    Dim tblFinanceTemp As DataTable

    tblAccounts = DeleteDuplicateFromDataTable(tblAccounts, "no")

    'Loop through to find financial information for each account
    For Each row As DataRow In tblAccounts.Rows
        Dim rowNo As Integer = row.Item("no")
        daFinance = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT branch, no, effective, desc_, code, empltype FROM [DmdOD] where no =" & rowNo, conn)

        daFinance.FillSchema(dsFinance, SchemaType.Source, "Finance")
        daFinance.Fill(dsFinance, "Finance")
        daFinance.FillSchema(dsFinanceTemp, SchemaType.Source, "FinanceTemp")

        Dim newRow As DataRow = dsFinanceTemp.Tables("FinanceTemp").NewRow()

        newRow("branch") = "central"

        tblFinance = dsFinance.Tables("Finance")
        tblFinanceTemp = dsFinanceTemp.Tables("FinanceTemp")
        For Each finRow As DataRow In tblFinance.Rows
            'count the rows to load into the dataTable
            Dim rowCount = (From r As DataRow In tblFinance.Rows Where CType(r("no"), Integer) = rowNo Select r).Count()
            Do While finRow.Item("no") = rowNo And rowCount <> 0
                tblFinanceTemp.ImportRow(finRow)
                rowCount -= 1
            Loop
            Exit For
        Next

        gridFinance.DataSource = tblFinanceTemp
        gridFinance.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        gridFinance.Attributes.Add("style", "table-layout:fixed; position: relative; z-index: 1")
        gridFinance.Height = 400
        gridFinance.Width = 200
        gridFinance.BorderWidth = 2
        gridFinance.DataBind()

        'this is the line the error is happening on
        tblAccounts.Rows.Add(gridFinance)
        Exit For
    Next

    GVAccounts.DataSource = tblAccounts
    GVAccounts.DataBind()

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Code for main Gridview:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GVAccounts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" 
        style="position: relative; margin-top: 10px" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="branch" HeaderText="Branch" 
                SortExpression="branch" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="no" HeaderText="Account" 
                SortExpression="account" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") + " " + Eval("surname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="sub" HeaderText="Sub" SortExpression="sub" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalAmount" HeaderText="Hold" 
                SortExpression="TotalAmount" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="loc" HeaderText="LOC" DataFormatString="{0:c}" SortExpression="loc" />


        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

I've tried googling about putting a gridview into a gridview. I've also tried googling the error I've gotten but haven't had any luck with either. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: This may not have to do so much with the nested GridViews, but with the data in the branch column. If you remove/comment out the nested GridView, do you still get the error?

Comment: No I don't, I commented out the code for the nested gridview and the code where it adds it to the parent one and my asp page loads fine

Comment: Ok, can we please see the code to your GridViews?

Comment: I don't have code for the second one since I was going to do it through the LoadData method, but I can show the code for my first one.

Comment: Added the code for the gridview

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the issue is. But I do know that this line `tblAccounts.Rows.Add(gridFinance)` doesn't do what you think it does. That will just add a string representation of that GridView to the table. You would want to iterate each row in the GridView and add them each individually to the table.

Comment: Hmmm interesting, I'll have to try what you suggest and see if that'll work, thanks.